# Python & Matplotlib: How to plot the range of bootstrap histogram plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to example the variance of a dataset, by bootstrap(resample) the data.

```
from numpy.random import randn

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

bins = arange(-5,6,0.5)
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(3000))
df.hist(ax=ax, bins=bins, alpha = 0.7, normed=True)

count_collection = []
for i in xrange(1,100):
    temp_df = df.sample(frac=0.5, replace=True)
    temp_df.hist(ax=ax, bins=bins, alpha = 0.25, normed=True)

    count, division = np.histogram(temp_df, bins=bins) 
    count_collection.append(count)
```

[image]

However, such plot is hard to see the limit. Is it possible to plot the upper/lower limit of the histogram, so it can be see clearer, maybe some thing like Boxplot for each bin?

[image]
<sub>(source: [matplotlib.org](http://matplotlib.org/_images/boxplot_demo_06.png))</sub>

or just curves with upper/lower limit to indicate range?

[image]

My main difficulty is extracting the max/min value for each bin (The `count_collection`)

UPDATE:

What would be a good way to plot the range?

```
count_collection = np.array(count_collection)
mx = np.max(count_collection,0)
mn = np.min(count_collection,0)

ax.plot(division[1:]-0.25, mx, '_', mew=1)
ax.plot(division[1:]-0.25, mn, '_', mew=1)
```

[image]

I find this is still hard to look, any suggestion?

Comment: You may want to look at the [`numpy.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) function, which does the binning without doing any plotting.  You can use it to get the data and then plot it however you like.

Comment: @BrenBarn I know `np.histogram`, and I actually use it to collect all the data. I just don't know how to get the max/min value from the value collection.

Comment: As a side note, shouldn't the `count` collect `temp_df`? Otherwise it seems to be just 100 repetitions of `df`...

Comment: @Aguy you are right. I made a mistake. Just corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the max and min you may use the following:

```
count_collection = np.array(count_collection)
mx = np.max(count_collection,0)
mn = np.min(count_collection,0)
```

The first line just changes from a list of 1d arrays to 2d array, so max and min can operate.

**edit:**

Since the original plot was normalized, it is hard to make sense of max and min of half the sample size. But you can do something like this:
    import numpy as np
    from numpy.random import randn
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

bins = np.arange(-5,6,0.5)
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(3000))
#df.hist(ax=ax, bins=bins, alpha = 0.7, normed=True)
histval, _ = np.histogram(df, bins=bins)

count_collection = []
for i in np.arange(1,100):
    temp_df = df.sample(frac=0.5, replace=True)
#    temp_df.hist(ax=ax, bins=bins, alpha = 0.25, normed=True)

    count, division = np.histogram(temp_df, bins=bins)
    count_collection.append(count)

count_collection = np.array(count_collection)
mx = np.max(count_collection,0)
mn = np.min(count_collection,0)

plt.bar(bins[:-1], histval, 0.5)
plt.plot(bins[:-1] + 0.25, mx*2)
plt.plot(bins[:-1] + 0.25, mn*2)
```

The 2x factor is due to the 2x smaller sample size when calculating the max and min.
[image]

Comment: Is there any suggestion on the data visualization? I update the plot in question. Is there any good way to plot the range? I think maybe error bar would a good choice?

Comment: This is tricky since you've used normalization. On the sample the bins are typically half the height if plotted to scale. So the problem is not well defined. I've added some code to show this.

Comment: Conceptually, why it is hard to make sense? A resampled normed data is still a distribution. The limt is just the limit derived from this normed distribution. I think this simply indicating the inherent random varability of the distribution.

Comment: As long as you take a 2x factor as in the answer above it may be what you were after.